# How do I ggplot a geom_bar with instance counts by year + a line graph with the sum of a column by year?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to replicate a graph like this in ggplot (I'm very new to R). I've managed to plot the bars but I'm unable to figure out the line.

[image: Reference]

My data would look roughly like this:

```
    uid casualties year
1     1         34 1999
2     2          1 1999
3     3          6 1999
4     4          1 2000
5     5          1 2000
6     6          1 2000
7     7          5 2001
8     8          1 2001
9     9          0 2001
10   10          1 2001
11   11          0 2002
12   12          0 2002
13   13          1 2002
14   14          1 2002
```

My bar graph would depict the number of row instances grouped by year, and my line graph would be the sum of casualties in that year. So for the data sample above, the plot should depict the following

```
year   instances (bar)   casualties (line)
1999   3                 41
2000   3                 3
2001   4                 7
2002   4                 2
```

So far my code is as follows:

```
casualties_by_year = aggregate(data["casualties"],by=data["year"],sum)
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(year))) +
 geom_bar(width=0.4, fill='darkorange') + # works fine
  geom_line(data=casualties_by_year, aes(x=year, y=casualties)) + # unexpected results
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

If I change the `year` in geom_line to `factor(year)`, it shows me the expected bar graph but no line.
[image]

What is my code missing?

Comment: @phiver ah that was unintentional, I was just changing factor(year) to year for the question and left that in by mistake. I've edited it

Comment: `ggplot(casualties_by_year , aes(x=year)) +  geom_col(aes(y =casualties), width=0.4, fill='darkorange') +  geom_line(aes(y= casualties))`. This is a guess because I don't have your data, but it works with the 2 records you show is your data.

Comment: ... or `ggplot(casualties_by_year , aes(x=factor(year), y= casualties)) +  geom_col(width=0.4, fill='darkorange') +  geom_line(aes(group = 1))`. The issue is that by mapping a discrete variable (factor(year)) on x ggplot2 will group your data by this variable, i.e. you will get a separate line for each year aka a point. Using group=1 (or group="foo" or ...). you tell ggplot2 to treat all obs. as one group.

Comment: @stefan that seems to plot number of casualties for both the histogram and line graph I think? What I'm looking for is the histogram should depict the total number of instances in the dataset grouped by year. For the line graph, I wanted it to depict the sum of the values in the casualties column grouped by year. Let me know if that's unclear, I could try and give an example

Comment: please, provide data so we can provide an answer, see [mcve]

Comment: Aw. Sorry. My fault. In that case you only have to add `group=1` to your code, i.e. `ggplot(data, aes(factor(year))) + geom_bar(width = 0.4, fill = "darkorange") + geom_line(data = casualties_by_year, aes(y = casualties, group = 1))`